# Does function occur only once If defined to a variable?

Tags: php, function

In case I have this function

```
<?php
function func() {
  return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
?>
```

If I called it like this

```
$array = func();
echo $array[0].$array[1].$array[2];
```

Is the function called only **once** and **copied** into `$array`? Or is it called for each `$array[x]`?

Is there any different from defining it like that and like this

```
echo func()[0].func()[1].func()[2];
```

Comment: The function is called when you call it. The **value** returned by the function in the first example is copied into `$array`. In the second example the function is called 3 times because this is how the code is written.

Comment: Easy enough to have tested this ... put an `echo 'YAR!';` in the function =)

Comment: @IncredibleHat oh, didn't think of that at all.

Comment: Echoing all kinds of stuff in all kinds of places leads to all kinds of discoveries! Like server 500s too... *cough* ;) Still a useful question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo func()[0].func()[1].func()[2]; // executed 3 times
```

or:

```
$res = func(); // executed one time
echo $res[0].$res[1].$res[2];
```

Each time when you read `()` after a function name this means that the function will be called (of course not while defining)

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: Which of those two logic applies on `loops` in something like this `foreach (clean_split($vars) as $var) {. . .}` or `while(clean_split($vars)) {. . .}`?

Comment: i don't get the question@Toleo

Answer (score 1):

It's called only once, and the result copied to `$array`. In the second example, it's called three times.